# How to stack 32bit zend debugger with builded from source php.so

Tags: php, apache, apache2.2, zend-debugger

Zend debugger depends on `libssl.0.9.8`, the one that is in repository just for `32bit` architecture.

Actual `debugger-64bit` don't want to use `32bit libssl.so` file with error (`php -m`):

> Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/ZendDebugger.so:  libssl.so.0.9.8: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

How is it possible to acquire right libssl.so for this debugger or stack `debugger-32bit` with built `php.so`